# Rewriting a Derivative with Logs & Sums & a Scalar

Tags: derivatives, summation, logarithms, partial-derivative

Consider the following derivative that contains two random variables ($x$ and $y$) and one constant scalar ($\beta$):

$\frac{\partial}{\partial \log(y)} \, \log(x+y)\beta$.

Let us define this derivative as $\Delta$, so:

$\Delta \equiv \frac{\partial}{\partial \log(y)} \, \log(x+y)\beta$.

Question: Can we rewrite the above definition to solve for the constant $\beta$?

In other words, how do we define $\beta$ as a function of $\Delta, x,$ and $y$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint :
\begin{align*}
\log(x+y) &= \log\left(x+e^{\log(y)}\right)
\end{align*}
Using this you get
\begin{align*}
\beta = \Delta \frac{x+y}{y}
\end{align*}